# "System program problem detected" During Login

Tags: login, password, login-screen

"System program problem detected" During Login with username and password and as Guest and no password. I can not login to Ubuntu. Is there a way to resolve this without reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Also, when "System program problem detected" box clears, vertical lines flicker on the display as if there's a bad video driver installed. This system has work fine previously and no changes have been made.